# How to Create and Retrive a product programmatically in Drupal commerce 2.x

Tags: commerce

I have created the store in Drupal commerce 2.x. I have added a product for the product type from the dashboard. Now i want to create Product grammatically  in  my custom module. how  this can be done Drupal 8 for Drupal commerce 2.x

Answer (score 1):

To create a product is similar to how you'd create a node:

```
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product;
use Drupal\commerce_price\Price;

$variation1 = ProductVariation::create([
  'type' => 'default',
   'sku' => '123',
   'price' => new Price('14.50', 'USD'),
]);
$variation1->save();

$variation2 = ProductVariation::create([
  'type' => 'default',
   'sku' => '1234',
   'price' => new Price('10.00', 'USD'),
]);
$variation2->save();

$product = Product::create([
   'type' => 'default',
   'title' => t('Product Title'),
    'variations' => [$variation1, $variation2],
]);
$product->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/56225927/7528823 or please see the documentation --- [Creating Products](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/products/product-management/code-recipes#creating-variations)